# fork to new cygwin terminal

Tags: c, cygwin, fork

I have this program that forks and I was wondering how to get it to fork to a separate terminal so the parent and child would have their own windows and stop fighting each other. I am trying to accomplish this with cygwin, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is that it's not possible. However, it can be hacked around by using two different programs, one that does the fork, and then the child executes a new shell which *might* open a new window, and let that shell run the second program.

Or you can use something like [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) to split the terminal window into two separate regions and use one region per process.